# mongoDB updateMany by query parameter and use a data from items

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a database:

```
[{  "itemName": "ball",
   "price": 20,
   "category": "sport",
   "discountPrice": 0
},
{  "itemName": "car",
   "price": 50,
   "category": "toys",
   "discountPrice": 0
}]
```

I need to set a discount price for instance for a query category="sport".
I have to take "price" of an item minus a discount and put a value to "discountPrise"

For instance req.query = {category:"sport"}, req.body = {discount: 0.9}
I wrote so

```
const putDiscount = async (req, res) => {
await Product.updateMany(req.query, {discountPrice: ${price*req.body.discount}})
res...}
```

How can I get a "price" of every item?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an update pipeline:

```
db.collection.update(
  {"category": "sport"},
  [{$set: {discountPrice: {$multiply: ["$price", req.body.discount]}}}],
  {multi: true}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Vo6AaOs0eK)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks very frightening But it works !
Pipeline is something interesting